# Dom Element undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have two global property

```
  htmlContentElement 
  htmlContentContainer
```

I set it in

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.htmlContentElement = document.getElementById("messageContent");
    this.htmlContentContainer = document.getElementById("messageContainer");
}
```

And i use this prperty in this method

```
setOcrMessage() {
    let originalContent = this.htmlContentElement.innerHTML;
    console.log(this.htmlContentElement);
    this.htmlContentElement.innerHTML = this.ocrInfo.message;
    if(this.ocrInfo.status) {
      this.htmlContentElement.style.color = "#168F48";
      this.htmlContentContainer.style.background = "rgb(236, 253, 240)";
    } else {
      this.htmlContentElement.style.color = "#e50000";
      this.htmlContentContainer.style.background = "rgb(251, 233, 235)";
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(this.htmlContentElement);
      this.htmlContentElement.innerHTML = originalContent;
      this.this.htmlContentElement.style.color = "#979797";
      this.htmlContentContainer.style.background = "white";
      this.htmlContentContainer.style.opacity = "1";
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

first console.log(this.htmlContentElement) return element
but second in setTimeout() return undefined

I execute setOcrMessage() in

```
constructor( private imageService: ImageService, private documentService: DocumentService,
  private ocrService: OcrService) {
    this.ocrMessageSubscription = this.ocrService.messageIfOcrCorrectly.subscribe(
      (res: ocrMessage) => {
        this.ocrInfo = res;
        this.setOcrMessage();
      }
    )
  }
```

Why htmlContentElement become undefined?
When i use 
  htmlContentElement and
  htmlContentContainer
property local in setOcrMessage() everything work fine.

Comment: Is the issue that you have an extra this in ``this.this.htmlContentElement.style.color = "#979797";``?

Comment: @HeikkiMäenpää thanks i set one this but this is not a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are losing the closure by using function, instead of

```
setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(this.htmlContentElement);
      this.htmlContentElement.innerHTML = originalContent;
      this.this.htmlContentElement.style.color = "#979797";
      this.htmlContentContainer.style.background = "white";
      this.htmlContentContainer.style.opacity = "1";
    }, 3000);
```

try to use arrow function

```
setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.htmlContentElement);
      this.htmlContentElement.innerHTML = originalContent;
      this.this.htmlContentElement.style.color = "#979797";
      this.htmlContentContainer.style.background = "white";
      this.htmlContentContainer.style.opacity = "1";
    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside `setTimeout` is not refers to the same `this` on parent block.
You can do something like this. Just get `this` into a separate variable.

```
    setOcrMessage() {
        let originalContent = this.htmlContentElement.innerHTML;
        console.log(this.htmlContentElement);
        this.htmlContentElement.innerHTML = this.ocrInfo.message;
        if(this.ocrInfo.status) {
          this.htmlContentElement.style.color = "#168F48";
          this.htmlContentContainer.style.background = "rgb(236, 253, 240)";
        } else {
          this.htmlContentElement.style.color = "#e50000";
          this.htmlContentContainer.style.background = "rgb(251, 233, 235)";
        }

        var self = this;

        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log(self.htmlContentElement);
          self.htmlContentElement.innerHTML = originalContent;
          self.htmlContentElement.style.color = "#979797";
          self.htmlContentContainer.style.background = "white";
          self.htmlContentContainer.style.opacity = "1";
        }, 3000);
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is the vanilla js solution since the above one is in ES6

Answer (score 1):

all two answers above are correct, but this concept is called 'lexical this' with arrow functions